# Semantic swagger error for a path parameter

Tags: rest, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am new to Swagger, and I have being fixing some errors I got after importing the .json file into `https://editor.swagger.io/` but I am getting this error.

> Declared path parameter "PARAMETER" needs to be defined within every
>   operation in the path (missing in "get"), or moved to the path-level
>   parameters object

Here is the part that is giving me the error:

```
'/api/v1/images/{PARAMETER}/{type}':
    get:
      tags:
        - Images
      summary: 'summar'
      operationId: DownloadFIle
      consumes: []
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: PARAMETER
          in: path
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: type
          in: path
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
          schema:
            uniqueItems: false
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/CloudImageInfo'
        '400':
          description: Bad Request
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ErrorResponse'
        '401':
          description: Unauthorized
          schema:
            type: string
        '404':
          description: Not Found
          schema:
            type: string
        '500':
          description: Server Error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ErrorResponse'
    post:
      tags:
        - Images
      summary: summary
      description: " description"
      operationId: UploadFile
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      produces:
        - application/json
      parameters:
        - name: imageFiles
          in: formData
          required: false
          type: array
          items: {}
          collectionFormat: multi
          uniqueItems: false
        - name: PARAMETER
          in: path
          required: true
          type: string
        - name: type
          in: path
          required: true
          type: string
      responses:
        '201':
          description: Success
          schema:
            uniqueItems: false
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/CloudImageInfo'
        '400':
          description: Bad Request
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ErrorResponse'
        '401':
          description: Unauthorized
          schema:
            type: string
        '500':
          description: Server Error
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ErrorResponse'
```

can anyone point me where to look or what can I fix?

Comment: - in: path should be placed upper than name, '-' it is like item into array.

Comment: There's an extra quote (or missing quote) in `summary: summar"`. Other than that, assuming that your definition contains `swagger: "2.0"`, it is valid and I don't see any errors in the Swagger Editor. Could it be a caching issue? Copy your YAML, then refresh the editor page and paste the YAML again - does the error still occur?

Comment: @VelikiiNehochuha the order of `in: path` and `name: ...` in parameters does not matter.

Comment: @Helen I corrected the summary single quote, it was a mistake while copy/pasting